# Working with dates in R

Tags: r, date, analysis

I have a dataset of transaction records with over 200 rows like so:

```
  balance  clientId     transactionDate   type_    Approval Date 
0 2038533   44291    2016-06-09 22:10:47   credit  2016-06-16 18:21:44                 
1 2038533   44291    2016-06-09 22:11:47   debit   2016-06-16 18:21:44         
2   61698   44291    2016-06-10 10:16:00   debit   2016-06-16 18:21:44
3 1538533   44291    2016-06-10 10:20:37   debit   2016-06-16 18:21:44         
4  561698   44291    2016-06-10 10:55:00   credit  2016-06-16 18:21:44           
5  511698   44291    2016-06-10 11:09:00   debit   2016-06-16 18:21:44
```

I'm trying to get the number of transactions by each client in the last 5 days before the approved date

Here's some code I have tried:

```
library(dplyr)

summarise(groupd, transactions = (`Approval Date`-days(5))
filter(groupd, `Approval Date` == (`Approval Date`-days(5)))
```

All to no avail. I cant seem to wrapy head around it. Any help whatsoever will be appreciated

Comment: you're trying to group your data set by client, so you want something like `by` in base R (please no), `group_by` in `dplyr`, or the `by` argument in `data.table`. happy googling.

Comment: I have grouped the datasetby client already using group_by.

Comment: Your example data does not actually have a transaction that is within 5 days of approval date...see my example

Answer (score 0):

May not be the most elegant way but here is how I would do it:
I am assuming that transactionDate and ApprovalDate column is in character format.

```
# Create df for transactions within last 5 days
df_last5days <- subset(df, as.Date(ApprovalDate) - as.Date(transactionDate) < 6)

# Create table of transactions
table(df_last5days$clientID)
```

OR, if you like 1-liner:

```
table(subset(df, as.Date(ApprovalDate) - as.Date(transactionDate) < 6)$clientID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to summarise the number of transactions(transactionDate) within 5 days period of approval date(ApprovalDate)? if so

data.table

```
dt[ApprovalDate-transactionDate < ddays(5) ,.N, by=list(clientID)]
# DT[ i,  j,  by ] # + extra arguments
#    |   |   |
#    |   |    -------> grouped by what?
#    |    -------> what to do? .N here summurise number of instances by group
#     ---> on which rows?
```

trial with inputs, I added some records that would satisfy the condition. I used lubridate package as to preserve the time data. as.Date() might work better if 5 days constraint are only based on date.

```
df<-read.table(text="
0 2038533,   44291    2016-06-09 22:10:47   credit  2016-06-16 18:21:44                 
1 2038533   44291    2016-06-09 22:11:47   debit   2016-06-16 18:21:44         
2   61698   44291    2016-06-10 10:16:00   debit   2016-06-16 18:21:44
3 1538533   44291    2016-06-10 10:20:37   debit   2016-06-16 18:21:44         
4  561698   44291    2016-06-10 10:55:00   credit  2016-06-16 18:21:44           
5 511698   44291    2016-06-10 11:09:00   debit   2016-06-16 18:21:44
6  511698   44292    2016-06-10 11:09:00   debit   2016-06-16 18:21:44
7  511692   44291    2016-06-13 11:09:00   debit   2016-06-16 18:21:44
7  511692   44292    2016-06-13 11:09:00   debit   2016-06-16 18:21:44
", stringsAsFactors = F)

library(data.table)
library(lubridate) #required for parse_date_time

# using data.table to clear the input, as well as parse the timedate
dt <- setDT(df)[,{t.Date=parse_date_time(paste0(V4,V5), "YmdHMS")
a.date=parse_date_time(paste0(V7,V8), "YmdHMS")
list(ID=V1, balance=V2, clientID=V3, transactionDate=t.Date, type_=V6, ApprovalDate=a.date)}]

# library(dplyr)
# glimpse(dt)
# Observations: 7
# Variables: 6
# $ ID              <int> 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
# $ balance         <chr> "2038533,", "2038533", "61698", "1538533", "561698", "511698", "511698"
# $ clientID        <int> 44291, 44291, 44291, 44291, 44291, 44291, 44292
# $ transactionDate <dttm> 2016-06-09 22:10:47, 2016-06-09 22:11:47, 2016-06-10 10:16:00, 2016-06-10 10:20:37, 2016-...
# $ type_           <chr> "credit", "debit", "debit", "debit", "credit", "debit", "debit"
# $ ApprovalDate    <dttm> 2016-06-16 18:21:44, 2016-06-16 18:21:44, 2016-06-16 18:21:44, 2016-06-16 18:21:44, 2016-...

dt[ApprovalDate-transactionDate<ddays(5) ,.N, by=list(clientID)]

$ clientID <int> 44291, 44292
$ N        <int> 1, 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `transactionDate` and `Approval_Date` are already a datetime variable, you can do:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(clientId) %>%
  filter(Approval_Date-transactionDate < 5) %>%
  summarize(num_of_transac = n())
```

otherwise, do:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>%
  mutate_at(c("transactionDate", "Approval_Date"), funs(parse_date_time(., "Ymd.HMS"))) %>%
  group_by(clientId) %>%
  filter(Approval_Date-transactionDate < 5) %>%
  summarize(num_of_transac = n())
```

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  clientId num_of_transac
     <int>          <int>
1    44291              2
2    44292              3
```

I've modified OP's example to demonstrate that this actually works.

**Data where `transactionDate` and `Approval_Date` already datetime:**

```
df = structure(list(balance = c(2038533L, 2038533L, 61698L, 1538533L, 
561698L, 511698L, 511698L, 5116123L, 511123L, 511244L), clientId = c(44291L, 
44291L, 44291L, 44291L, 44291L, 44291L, 44292L, 44292L, 44292L, 
44292L), transactionDate = structure(c(1465510247, 1465510307, 
1465553760, 1465554037, 1465728900, 1465729740, 1465556940, 1466075340, 
1466075340, 1466161740), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), type_ = c("credit", "debit", "debit", "debit", "credit", 
"debit", "debit", "debit", "debit", "debit"), Approval_Date = structure(c(1466101304, 
1466101304, 1466101304, 1466101304, 1466101304, 1466101304, 1466446904, 
1466446904, 1466446904, 1466446904), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"))), .Names = c("balance", "clientId", "transactionDate", 
"type_", "Approval_Date"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

**Data where `transactionDate` and `Approval_Date` *not* datetime:**

```
df = structure(list(balance = c(2038533L, 2038533L, 61698L, 1538533L, 
561698L, 511698L, 511698L, 5116123L, 511123L, 511244L), clientId = c(44291L, 
44291L, 44291L, 44291L, 44291L, 44291L, 44292L, 44292L, 44292L, 
44292L), transactionDate = c("2016-06-09.22:10:47", "2016-06-09.22:11:47", 
"2016-06-10.10:16:00", "2016-06-10.10:20:37", "2016-06-12.10:55:00", 
"2016-06-12.11:09:00", "2016-06-10.11:09:00", "2016-06-16.11:09:00", 
"2016-06-16.11:09:00", "2016-06-17.11:09:00"), type_ = c("credit", 
"debit", "debit", "debit", "credit", "debit", "debit", "debit", 
"debit", "debit"), Approval_Date = c("2016-06-16.18:21:44", "2016-06-16.18:21:44", 
"2016-06-16.18:21:44", "2016-06-16.18:21:44", "2016-06-16.18:21:44", 
"2016-06-16.18:21:44", "2016-06-20.18:21:44", "2016-06-20.18:21:44", 
"2016-06-20.18:21:44", "2016-06-20.18:21:44")), .Names = c("balance", 
"clientId", "transactionDate", "type_", "Approval_Date"), row.names = 0:9, class = "data.frame")
```